# passing array through Net::HTTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

I'm trying to pass an array through Net::HTTP to a ruby

```
def send_p
  x = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://example_domain/example'), to_send)
  render text: x
end

def to_send
  {
    param_a: "foo",
    param_b: [1,2,3]
  }
end
```

but when check the params in `http://example_domain/example` is getting me

```
{
  "param_a"=>"foo",
  "param_b"=>"3",
  "action"=>"my_method",
  "controller"=>"my_controller"
}
```

what can I do to receive the array in the proper way: [1,2,3]

Comment: which ruby you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `HTTParty`:

```
x = HTTParty.post(URI.parse('http://example_domain/example'), to_send)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the array to string and then do the inverse when getting the params from the response.

Convert to String before to send it

```
param_b: [1,2,3].to_s
```

You will receive exactly as you sent it

```
"param_b"=>"[1,2,3]"
```

Convert it back to Array

```
eval(params[:param_b])
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: eval of params will give freedom to hackers to execute any code and query.